# How to POLL an iOS app and check if it has resigned active?

Tags: ios, ios7, appdelegate

When an iOS app has resigned active, it is still running. Timers still run, and HTTP operations continue.

How can I **poll** the app to determine if it has resigned active?

Please know that I'm not interested in observing `UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification`, nor setting some flags in the `appWillResignActive` block. There are situations where code is run *after* the app has resigned active and will miss notifications, and the app delegate cannot be modified. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationState`? Or is it not good enough for your case / what you need?

Comment: Wow, that was easy. I spent my whole time searching the docs for `UIApplicationDelegate`, not `UIApplication`. Thank you for the quick answer. Wonderful.